# Executar uma função assíncrona no react-native apenas a primeira vez que ela for chamada

Tags: javascript, react-native, async, expo, qrcode

Estou usando a função do componente Camera do expo-camera

```
onBarCodeScanned={(event) => {
      handleQRCode(event);
}}
```

E toda vez que há um código de barra ele chama meu `handleQRCode`, porém apenas de passar o QRCode na frente da câmera ele já chama essa função mais de uma vez, (geralmente mais de 3 vezes com uma passada bem rápida), porém dentro do meu `handleQRCode` eu chamo uma API, e como o `handleQRCode` é chamado muitas vezes acontecem muitas requisições a API, já testei colocar variáveis booleanas, tanto "normais" tanto usando o `useState` pra enquanto estiver ocorrendo a requisição ele não fazer novas requisições, mas não funciona, não sei mais o que fazer, alguém pode me ajudar?

Código do `handleQRCode`:

```
const [visibleModalBuscando, setVisibleModalBuscando] = useState(false);

async function handleQRCode(event) {
    if (!visibleModalBuscando) {
      setVisibleModalBuscando(true);
      let result = await buscarDadosParaHome(event.data);
      if (result) {
        navigation.navigate("Home");
      } else {
        Alert.alert(
          "QRCode inválido",
          "Esse QRCode não é válido!\n Tente novamente! Se o problema persistir contate o responsável!"
        );
      }
      setVisibleModalBuscando(false);
    }
  }
```